# Multiple && in an if statement. Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Would someone be able to tell me if I am using the correct syntax in this if statement. I need it to carry out the the `window.alert()` if all of the conditions are true.

```
if (outcome == images[0] && outcome1 == images[1] && outcome2 == images[2]) 
{
    window.alert("turner")
}
```

This is inside a XHTML document and throws an error in Firefox.

Comment: Yes, the syntax is correct.

Comment: You can run the same in browser debugger to check for syntax by evaluating all to true

Comment: This is an XHTML document, and when I try to test it in firefox, it throws back an error saying that there's a problem with the && operator. Does anybody have an idea why this might be?

Comment: It worked for me, if (1 == 1 && 2 == 2 && 3 == 3)  { .. }

Comment: i try this code in firefox it will work

    if (true && true && true) 
    {
        window.alert("turner")
    }

Comment: The syntax is correct but you might need to encode the ampersands: 

& -> &amp;  && -> &amp;&amp;

Comment: I'm not experienced with XHTML but have you tried wrapping the script contents in a CDATA block? Or make it an external script.

Comment: @ToniToniChopper that seemed to be the issue. Thanks, but I thought it wouldn't have mattered if I enclosed the code in scripting tags. I thought the code would then be interpreted as pure javascript.

Comment: @user3087015 it matters as it is part of a XML document - the parser will read it and throw at the unencoded `&` (same applies to `<` and `>` if I remember correctly). I believe you can make the js external through `<script src="..."></script>` or use a CDATA block to don't have to escape the characters.

Comment: Yes thank you very much the CDATA tags work also. I am not very experienced with JavaScript so I did not know about CDATA.

Comment: CDATA isn't part of the Javascript, it's part of the XHTML document. You could alternatively just declare your document as HTML5 and not have to worry about this. Though best practice would be to not have scripts inlined in your HTML anyway but rather have them in separate files.